# how to make vertical mirror of canvas.drawbitmap for drawing app

Tags: android

i have created an drawing app which is working fine. now all i want is to make vertical mirror of drawing path.
the code for drawing is

```
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

//draw the view - will be called after touch event
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);




}

//register user touches as drawing action
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();
    //respond to down, move and up events
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
        drawPath.reset();
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }
    //redraw
    invalidate();
    return true;

}
```

from where i should start to make a vertical mirror of path.
i searched for it and i get some info which was about

```
BitmapDrawable flip(BitmapDrawable d){
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.preScale(-1, 1);
Bitmap src = d.getBitmap();
Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(),      m, false);
dst.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
return new BitmapDrawable(dst); }
```

how can i use this code in my app. 
any help will be appreciated.